# How to deploy a JFrame in multiple monitor configuration

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-monitors

I'd like to build an app that has 2 windows. 
The first one should always be in the first monitor, and can't be maximized. 
The second one should be launched in second monitor (a perfect example is like PowerPoint's presentation mode), is running "on top" of any other applications' window, and always maximized. This window is launched using a listener given to the first window.
Note that these "monitors" may be LCD projectors used in presentations, or real desktop computer monitors.

I know that there exists GraphicsEnvironment API, and we can know whether our monitor configuration is treated as a single monitor, or treated separately. But, I don't know how to implement it. I mean, since screen configurations can be treated differently depending on their graphic cards, how do we validate them?

For example, if there are 3 monitors treated as a single monitor with large resolution, then perhaps we can set a coordinate x0 for second window as : total_width * 2 / 3.
But, what if it is treated as seperate monitors..?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you look at this link : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/2d/spec/j2d-awt.fm6.html, This might help. its really old though but you will be able to find something similar in new java version

Comment: I think that even if multiple monitors are treated as "one" in the sense that the displayed content is spread on all of them as it would be on one giant monitor, you can still get each monitor individually with: GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices(); and then set your frame on whatever screen you desire using gs[i].setFullScreenWindow( myJFrame );

Comment: wow.. thanks for the quick responses. I'll try them ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Zecas : Yes, it worked out well. Sorry for not posting the answer here. I totally forgot.
So, the solution is exactly as what ShivanDragon has stated, we can get each monitor individually by obtaining our GraphicsEnvironment first, and then get our screen devices from the Environment:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
```

After that, just use:

```
gs[_screen_index].setFullSCreenWindow(_frame)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this to work for me on Ubuntu Linux.. with an Nvidia video card.. Not sure if my particular issue has to do with how my displays are configured with X perhaps not appearing to Java as discrete displays or something along those lines..