# JOptionPane pops up on second monitor

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor set up that isn't playing nice with the program I'm making:

My JFrame shows up on my main/default monitor. The frame show a few buttons which prompt JOptionPanes to be opened. When any of them are clicked the JOptionPane opens on the second monitor at the adjoining edge of the main monitor. Every so often it displays normally, centered in the JFrame but 19 times in 20 it pops up on the second monitor. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should read about GraphicsEnvironment. It enables you control your Jframes when using Multiple Monitors. Similar thread exist at [How to deploy a JFrame in multiple monitor configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688409/how-to-deploy-a-jframe-in-multiple-monitor-configuration)